# Android - Stream an mp3 file from Android device to windows PC

Tags: android, stream, audio-streaming

I am trying to write an application that could stream music files from an android device to a windows PC over a local Wifi network.Below is my Question.

I am able to connect the android device to a PC(I have a written small c# application that use sockets for connection) through TCP using sockets and transfer some small messages between them using the local wifi network.But in order to stream an mp3 file from Android device to PC, which protocol should I use and why?

EDIT: I am planning to use VLC library for c#.net to develop the music player for windows.So this application is going to stream the media from Android.

Comment: This is not so much an Android question as it is a question of what client software you expect to use on the PC to listen to the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Use RTSP. and look into the following:

https://netty.io/

http://www.live555.com/